# What is purpose of abstract property in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop

We have the `abstract` attribute of methods and properties in MATLAB R2014b, and I know the purpose of `abstract` attribute for methods. We can call functions in that method and define it in the superclass of a class. What I'm confused about is the purpose of the `abstract` attribute for a property in MATLAB. How do we use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of abstract properties (and abstract methods) is to allow the [creation of interfaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/defining-interfaces.html):

> The basic idea of an interface class is to specify the properties and methods that each subclass must implement without defining the actual implementation.

For example, you can define an abstract `Car` with the definition

```
classdef (Abstract) Car
    properties(Abstract) % Initialization is not allowed
      model
      manufacturer
    end
end
```

The abstract properties `model` and `manufacturer` cannot be initialized (that would be like instantiating an abstract class) and all classes that inherit from `Car` **must specify their value for the subclass to be concrete**.
If the properties were not abstract, the subclass would simply inherit them.
Making the properties abstract forms a contract of sorts that says "for you to be a usable (concrete) car you must have a `model` and `manufacturer` defined".

Therefore, in the definition

```
classdef FirstEveryManCar < Car
    properties
      model = 'T';
      manufacturer = 'Ford';
    end
end
```

the property definitions are compulsory for the class to not be made abstract automatically (which you could do if you have long class hierarchies).

Comment: Thank you for answer. So we should define `Car` class with abstract properties of `model` and `manufacturer`  and without any initialization. Is that true?

Comment: @user2991243 I have expanded the answer to better  explain the purpose and behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There is a significant consequence for setter/getter methods (i.e. set.Property & get.Property).

Due to the way Matlab works, you can only implement setter/getter methods inside the class definition file of the class that declares the property. Therefore if you want to ensure a property is defined in the interface, but require implementation specific setter/getter methods, then declaring the property Abstract in the interface class ensures the subclass redefines the property and enables that class to define its own setter/getter methods.

## Example 1 (Does not work)

### Superclass

```
classdef (Abstract) TestClass1 < handle
    properties
        Prop
    end
end
```

### Subclass

```
classdef TestClass2 < TestClass1
    methods
        function obj = TestClass2(PropVal)
            if nargin>0
                obj.Prop = PropVal;
            end
        end

        function set.Prop(obj, val)
            if ~isnumeric(val)
                error('Not a number!');
            end
            obj.Prop = val;
        end
    end
end
```

## Example 2 (The correct way)

### Superclass

```
classdef (Abstract) TestClass1 < handle

    properties (Abstract)
        Prop
    end
end
```

### Subclass

```
classdef TestClass2 < TestClass1
    properties
        Prop
    end
    methods
        function obj = TestClass2(PropVal)
            if nargin>0
                obj.Prop = PropVal;
            end
        end
        function set.Prop(obj, val)
            if ~isnumeric(val)
                error('Not a number!');
            end
            obj.Prop = val;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any example where you really need it, but it is typically used when a abstract superclass uses properties without having a reasonable default. This is a extremely trimmed down example, but imagine `welcome` implementing a full user interface while `welcomeGer` fills all required properties to provide it in german language:

```
%welcome.m
classdef welcome
    properties(Abstract)
        text
    end
    methods
        function printText(obj)
            disp(obj.text)
        end

    end
end

%welcomeGer.m
classdef welcomeGer<welcome
    properties
        text='Willkommen in unserem Hotel'
    end

end
```

Alternative you could skip the definition of `text` at all, but then matlab would not throw an error when you forget to initialize `text`